# How to set text file content to bean property using Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have a text file which contains data. I want to set this data to a String instance variable.

I know I can do it using Java I/O, read the file and set it's content to String variable.

But is there a simplistic way to initialize the String using Spring configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using properties file with this xml tags:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:YourFile.properties" />
    </bean>
```

And use the values as ${your_key}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using `Resource` and then use getFile() on resource. Check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html) spring documentation.
And better example [here](http://aredko.blogspot.com/2010/10/injecting-file-dependency-into-spring.html).